# UITableViewCell - Missing the MOVE lines in Edit Mode

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uitableview

I'm flummoxed as to what I may have done to cause this, but it seems that the lines that represent (and allow) MOVING of a UITableViewCell have disappeared when I enter edit mode. The delete button is there.

Anyone know what method or methods control that (usually default) cell accessory from being displayed when a user enters edit mode?

Thanks!

Comment: Hard to tell without seeing your code but I would suspect that you add your own views to the cell directly (instead of the cell's `contentView`).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I double-checked, and everything is in the contentView.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I was missing this method:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView moveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)fromIndexPath toIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)toIndexPath{


}
```

Thank you, Git!